# Reshape Tensorflow model batch dimension into time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, reshape, tensor

I'm trying to reshape a Tensorflow model's input along the batch dimension. I want to combine some of the batch samples into a time-series so I can feed it into an LSTM layer.

Specifically, I have 1024 samples and I'd like to put them into groups of 64 timesteps with the result being 16 batches of 64 timesteps, each timestep having the original 24 features.

```
 #input tensor is (1024, 24)
 inputLayer = Input(shape=(24,))

 #I want it to be (16, 64, 24)
 reshapedLayer = layers.Reshape([64, 24])(inputLayer)
 lstmLayer = layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu')(reshapedLayer)
```

This compiles but throws a runtime error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  
Input to reshape is a tensor with 24576 values, but the requested shape has 1572864
```

I understand what the error is telling me, but I'm not sure the right way to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this could work for you:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(24,))

x = tf.reshape(inputs, (16, 64, 24))
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

# dummy data
inputs = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1024, 24))

outputs = model(inputs)
```

Replacing the Reshape layer with `tf.reshape`.